# Numeric function of $e^x$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Write central derivative function of :
$f’’(x)$ where $f(x)=e^x$

Conditions : $f(x+h)$ , $f(x-2h)$ , $f(x)$ should appear only .

I solved using Taylor series the lecturer says it’s O($h^2$) but I got O(h).

Can someone help please

Comment: Why the down rate i would make it better if there’s something annoying in my post

Comment: Do you mean $f(x+h), f(x-h)$? Because the central derivative is defined as $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$, so there is no $f(x-2h)$ involved.

Comment: No that’s the point they want using only the functions above

Comment: It’s not Symmetrical they wrote : “ Write central derivative approximation using those functions only “

Comment: Wait, you're asking about the second derivative. So do you want to find $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ as the central derivative of $f^{\prime}(x)$, or do you want the central derivative of $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$, which would approximate $f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)$?

Comment: With Taylor series till O($h^4$) and using central derivative of $f’(x)$

Comment: Using Taylor of $f(x+h)$ and $f(x-2h) $ I get 2 equations  . And additional equation using central dervitive of $f’(x)$. Finally I solve the 3 equations and I get error : O(h) + O($h^2$)

Comment: I want the central derivative of $f’’(x)$ but not the known formula my jumps are not equal forward $h$ and backward $2h$

Comment: So you want $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = \dots$ or $f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x) = \dots$?

Comment: $f’’(x) = ..$ with error

Comment: OK, see my answer below. I get $O(h)$ just as you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Taylor's theorem, we have \begin{align*}&f(x+h) = f(x) + f^{\prime}(x)h + \frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^2 + O(h^3) \text{ and}\\ &f(x-2h) = f(x) - 2f^{\prime}(x)h + 2f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^2 + O(h^3)\end{align*} Thus \begin{align*}2f(x+h)+f(x-2h) = 3f(x)+3f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^2 + O(h^3)\end{align*} which gives \begin{equation*}f^{\prime\prime}(x) = \frac{2f(x+h)+f(x-2h)-3f(x)}{3h^2} + O(h)\end{equation*} If we go one term further, we get \begin{align*}&f(x+h) = f(x) + f^{\prime}(x)h + \frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^2 + \frac{1}{6}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)h^3 + O(h^4) \text{ and}\\ &f(x-2h) = f(x) - 2f^{\prime}(x)h + 2f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^2 - \frac{4}{3}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)h^3 + O(h^4)\end{align*} so \begin{equation*}4f(x+h)-f(x-2h) = 3f(x) + 6f^{\prime}(x) + 2f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)h^3 + O(h^4) \quad (*)\end{equation*} If we truncate the two equations at the $h$ term instead, we get \begin{equation*}f(x+h)-f(x-2h) = 3f^{\prime}(x)h + O(h^2)\end{equation*} This gives an expression for $f^{\prime}(x)$ that we can substitute into $(*)$, giving \begin{equation*}4f(x+h)-f(x-2h) =3f(x)+2\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-2h)}{h}\right) +2f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)h^3 + O(h^4)\end{equation*} This rearranges to \begin{equation*}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x) = \frac{4f(x+h)-f(x-2h)-3f(x)}{2h^3}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-2h)}{h^4}+O(h)\end{equation*}

Comment: But shouldn’t it be till O($h^4$)  so that the final is $f’’’(x)$

Comment: In your comment above, you said you wanted "f′′(x)=.. with error". If you want $f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)$ with error then I can edit my answer.

Comment: Because when we get the original formula we do it with O($h^4$) anyway I am only worried about O(h) or O(h^2) I hope it isn’t O(h^2) because then my answer is wrong

Comment: Can you please I would love to see an edit thanks a lot for helping

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the original formula" - can you clarify?

Comment: $f(x+h)-f(x-h)/2h$ we write Taylor series till O($h^4$)

Comment: Does my edited answer help?